# How to create multiple layers of cycle with MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I do something like this in MS Word? So far what I've being able to do is just a single layer of cycle using the Cycle option of SmartArt.

[image: cycles in cycles]

How can I bring in more cycles inside a cycle?

If that's not possible to do in Word alone, I would be open to other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I would do this manually. Especially if you are restricted to Office tools only.

The black lines would be created by adding simple boxes with rounded corners. The detail boxes would be added over the top manually. This would only take a few minutes to do. Use grouping if you need to move or resize things (select the appropriate boxes, right-click and group).

Even if using Microsoft Visio, I'd probably still do this manually as anything else would be more effort to do than would be worth it.

The only exception to this would be if I needed to create many similar looking diagrams with different data on a regular basis. In that case, I would create a template in MS Visio but this is certainly a non-trivial exercise to do properly, especially with the different colours you are using.